# Math display in Microsoft Edge

Tags: browser, microsoft-edge

Mathematical expressions in some webpages (e.g. wikipedia) are not displayed properly if I use Microsoft Edge. We can visit the following link, for example.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equation

Compare the following picture (Microsoft Edge)

[image]

with (Google Chrome)
[image]

In Edge, we see that equations are truncated. I have no problem if I use Internet Explorer or Google Chrome. On the other hand, math in Stackexchange is displayed properly in Edge. Is this a problem of the browser or the webpage? Are there any solutions?

Comment: what is the problem in the attached picture? what is the address of the site?

Comment: @Máté Juhász, I edited the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edge is a new browser and has new software written into it. New technology always has bugs. What you are witnessing is the interpretation of images and margins and maybe even "padding" -- these are style techniques for writing web pages. It's imperfect and there are techniques for each web browser; that's what web programmers are faced with. Wait a while before new techniques come available for the webmasters to figure out. It's not one-code-fits all sadly. It's what really get me frustrated when I wrote some of my first web pages that looked great on one browser and terrible on another. Growing pains of technology it is truly a nightmare for developers.